# Regular MySQL select query to Crosstab query

Tags: mysql

I have the created the following query which works fine, but need the values in a single row w/single header.

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') AS febl_Month,    

IF (SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth) IS NULL, SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth, 
SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) - SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth)) AS febl_remaining

FROM      tblweeklyebl RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID 
WHERE tblcom.omstatusID Like 'Closed'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m')
```

This gives me the following output:

```
febl_Month  febl_remaining
2014-01 42550
2014-02 33200
2014-03 42950
2014-04 30192
2014-05 48216
2014-06 58650
2014-07 41451
2014-08 1775
```

But I need the results to look like this?

```
Jan   Feb   Mar...
42550 33200 42950...
```

Comment: Why don't you do it by your programming language?

Comment: to do that you will need to know the number of rows this query will return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to know the number of rows to return.. so you can fake a pivot table.. but this would give the correct results... I added another collumn.. SELECT 1 as id.. to your original SELECT so we can pivot off of that fake id to make it rows to columns

## QUERY:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-01' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jan',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-02' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Feb',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-03' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Mar',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-04' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Apr',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-05' THEN febl_remaining END) 'May',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-06' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jun',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-07' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jul',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN '2014-08' THEN febl_remaining END) 'Aug'
    SUM(febl_remaining) as 'Total febl',
    AVG(febl_remaining) as 'Average febl'
FROM
(   SELECT 
        1 as id, 
        DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') AS febl_Month,    
        IF 
        (   SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth) IS NULL, 
              SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth), 
              SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) - SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth)
        ) AS febl_remaining
    FROM      tblweeklyebl 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID 
    WHERE tblcom.omstatusID Like 'Closed'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m')
) t 
GROUP BY t.id
```

[DEMO:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65a76/1)

## RESULTS:

```
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| Jan   |   Feb  |  Mar  |  Apr  |  May  |  Jun  |  Jul  |  Aug |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
| 42550 |  33200 | 42950 | 30192 | 48216 | 58650 | 41451 | 1775 |
+-------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

## EDIT:

to make it dynamic you should try

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jan',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%02') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Feb',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%03') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Mar',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%04') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Apr',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%05') THEN febl_remaining END) 'May',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%06') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jun',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%07') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Jul',
    MAX(CASE febl_month WHEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%08') THEN febl_remaining END) 'Aug'
    SUM(febl_remaining) as 'Total febl',
    AVG(febl_remaining) as 'Average febl'

FROM
(   SELECT 
        1 as id, 
        DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') AS febl_Month,    
        IF 
        (   SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth) IS NULL, 
              SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth), 
              SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) - SUM(DISTINCT weEstBuildLgth)
        ) AS febl_remaining
    FROM      tblweeklyebl 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblcom ON tblweeklyebl.comID = tblcom.omID 
    WHERE tblcom.omstatusID Like 'Closed'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m')
) t 
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: John, thank you so much.. worked perfectly.. was missing a closing bracket here:
     `SUM(DISTINCT tblcom.omEstBuildLgth) <----------`

Comment: @jlig oh sorry mustve not copied it over correctly fixed with edit.. glad it works for you.. as the months go by you'll have to add more rows but it'll do the trick :)

Comment: One more thing.. need to make the '2014-01' dates dynamic.. tried to add in: DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') in place of date but get "tblcom.omActCompDate" unknown column?

Comment: @jlig what are you trying to compare it with? are you trying to compare `DATE_FORMAT(tblcom.omActCompDate, '%Y-%m') ` to `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01') `??

Comment: @jlig i think i understand what you are asking.. see my edit for a more dynamic way with DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%01')

Comment: I'm comparing just the "Year & Month" parts of the date field to today's "Year & Month". otherwise I'll have to manually update this report when the year changes to 2015.

Comment: John, that did it! nice query.. much appreciated

Comment: John, Is it possible to add in a Total & Average value? (of all months)

Comment: @jlig ok edited... look at the select I added SUM and AVG to the query

Comment: John, looks like those calculations are way too high.. getting 2800973 (Total), and 96585 (Avg). The actual total should be 298984 and avg should be 37373. (I tried adding in Distinct but no change)

Comment: @jlig on my side the counts are correct.. see fiddle... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65a76/8

Comment: if thats not working then you may have to select from it... the only thing I can think of is it would be counting everything... but that doesn't make sense because your inner query should be filtering everything out

Comment: @jlig try running the inner query again.. make sure the results are what you were expecting before and that the data isn't changed.. if you can ensure that then I honestly dont know why its doing that.